# Register mouse events on overlapping Elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, mouseevent

In my svg image i draw a lot of paths (and other elements) some of which are partly transparent and may overlap each other.

How can I make sure that a mouse event such as a click is received by listeners of all elements and not only the topmost.

Basic example (assumeing A,B,C have the same coordinates and sizes):

```
<g id="parent">
  <rect id="A" .../>
  <rect id="B" .../>
  <rect id="C" .../>
</g>
```

In this example the desired outcome would be that a click on rectangle C (the topmost) is registered by listeners on A,B,C

Using google I learned that I could dispatch the event myself by registering a listener to parent and then checking for affected child elements however I'm wondering if there is a better solution or library.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only solution. The lower elements simply won't get the click event if they're overlapped by something else.

Comment: I saw this library but haven't had a chance to try it yet. It could be a good fit. https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~joh024/Research/D3js/SelNavSVG/SelNavSVG.html

Answer (score 1):

With jquery++ you can find which elements are at a given position even if they are behind other elements, you can do something simple like:

```
$("#parent").on("click",function(ev){
    $(this).children().within(ev.offsetX,ev.offsetY)...; //filter the elements
});
```

[**http://jquerypp.com/#within**](http://jquerypp.com/#within)

Comment: That's a good idea, but I haven't been able to get within working in SVGs. See their example http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/akSQD/light/ and compare with my version, having only replaced DIVs with SVG rects: http://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/akSQD/40/

Comment: I think you need to pass the event object in your function, there.